# Sublime Text 2 Keeps Growing due to Backup folder

Tags: backup, text-editors, plugins, sublime-text-2, extension

My Sublime Text 2 Installation folder keeps growing as the backup folder getting bigger. I think it is due to package control plugin. Every time, it updates, it creates dated folder in **Backup**.

Is there a way to remove this automated backup? Are there any settings in package control that I can modify?  please help.

Here is the backup folder.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This folder is created by Package Control, whenever a package is upgraded or deleted. It is there as a backup (well, duh :) ) in case something goes wrong during the process, or you want to revert. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to ever be pruned, hence the accumulation over time. If everything is fine with Package Control, and all plugins are working properly, you can safely delete the folders in `Backup`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have my own batch script that creates a zipped version of ST2 everyday, so that if something goes wrong I can revert it back. And this backup folder is causing issue with it. Anyways, I have to live with it.

Comment: Actually, I figured out a work around. In the package Control.sublime-settings, I added a `"auto_upgrade_frequency": 8;` to specify check for updrade only every 8 hours, this would make sure that it does not keep looking for upgrade and create those folders.